# PROMOTED_OBJECT return error when create AdSet in php

Tags: php, events, sdk, facebook-php-sdk, pixel

I have a custom conversion event named "ValuableAction"
I'm trying to create an adSet with this PROMOTED_OBJECT in php like this

```
AdSetFields::PROMOTED_OBJECT => array
    AdPromotedObjectFields::PIXEL_ID => "262575505667044",
    AdPromotedObjectFields::EVENT_ID => "211270220041369",
    AdPromotedObjectFields::CUSTOM_EVENT_TYPE => 'OTHER'
),
```

But the api return this error "(#100) Param promoted_object[event_id] must be a valid event id"

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

I know it has been a while since this question was asked but I was having the same problem and I couldn't find anything on facebook api docs.

Luckily I was able to create an adset with a custom conversion.

The promoted object look like this:

```
promoted_object: {
    pixel_id: "<your_pixel_id/>",
    pixel_rule: "write down here the custom conversion rule",
    custom_event_type: "the custom conversion <custom_event_type/>"
}
```

You can get the custom conversion rule making a request to:

```
https://graph.facebook.com/v3.2/<AD_ACCOUNT_ID/>?fields=customconversions{name,custom_event_type,pixel,rule}
```

I hope this helps anyone facing the same problem.

Answer (score 0):

You can get the custom conversion rules information by making a request like this:

```
https://graph.facebook.com/v3.2/<AD_ACCOUNT_ID>/customconversions?fields=["pixel","rule","custom_event_type","name"]
```

And fill out the promoted object look like this (all variables come from the previous API):

```
AdSetFields::PROMOTED_OBJECT => [
    AdPromotedObjectFields::CUSTOM_CONVERSION_ID => "<id>",
    AdPromotedObjectFields::CUSTOM_EVENT_TYPE => "<custom_event_type>",
    AdPromotedObjectFields::PIXEL_ID => "<pixel->id>",
    AdPromotedObjectFields::PIXEL_RULE => "<rule>",
]
```